# How to hide all console errors

Tags: .htaccess, console, hide

How to hide all console errors in web page by using `.htaccess`?

The code I'm currently using is not working

```
 php_flag display_errors off
```

Comment: Whether it's possible this way depends on your web server and the way PHP runs on it. PHP needs to be running as an Apache module for this, and Apache needs to be configured to parse .htaccess files and accept `php_flag` statements. If you're unsure about any of this, you should talk to your server administrator

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `.htaccess` is being taken into consideration by Apache. Just put inside your `.htaccess`:

```
# the following should issue a 500 error
LoremipsumdolorSITAMET
```

If your website still works after you place the above gibberish, your `.htaccess` is not read by Apache. In that case **contact your Admin**

If, on the other hand, you get a `500 error` (or any other, really) ask your Admin to allow flag setting in .htaccess